# Talend : Generate files dynamically

Tags: etl, talend

I'm working on a projet with Talend (TOS 5.2.2) which aims to split one data (.dat) file into many files. The .dat file structure is like this:

```
countryA|CountryCode|Name
town|Countrycode|NAme
countryB|CountryCode|Name
town|Countrycode|NAme
town|Countrycode|NAme
town|Countrycode|NAme
countryC|CountryCode|Name
town|Countrycode|NAme 
town|Countrycode|NAme
```

I want to generate dynamically files, and every file contains :  A Country and their related town (based on CountryCode).

No database must be used.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you stuck with something specific? Please update your question to include such information.

Comment: what do you mean with `(based on CountryCode)`? Is there a look-up table?

Comment: On input file, do all the towns of a country follow country declaration? What is the format of the output record?

Comment: @Endoro : There is no look-up table, only files are used. I meant that every file must contains the Country and the town having the same countryCode

Comment: @MD ND : Yes, all towns of country follow country declaration.THe output record is a File.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a tJavaRow after the dat input.

At the start define a

> String currCntry = "";
>   int prevCntryCode = -1 ;

In the tJavaRow you should compare the Actual cntrycode with the previous one, if it isn't matching, then you should make `currCntry = row1.Country` After that, you should have a simple tFileOutPutDelimited where the name is set like this:  currCntry + ".DAT"

If you run this, the output dat will contain the country rows aswell, what you can do is when you found a new country you manually set the first row to be a "header" row.